# CSS scaling is not working properly in IE10

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, svg

I have tried to scale the following SVG path. This works fine in chrome and firefox. But in IE10 it is not working. Any suggestions? Please find my code below.

```css
.two {
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out 0.5s;
}

#scale {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#scale {
  border: 1px blue solid;
}

.grow:hover {
  transform: scale(2.0);
  /*-ms-transform: scale(2.0);*/
  -webkit-transform: scale(2.0);
}
```

```html
<svg width="220" height="220">
  <g transform="translate(110,110)">
    <path d="M0 -43.3 50 43.3 -50 43.3Z" fill="yellow" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2"
          id="scale" class="grow two" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As you've seen by experiment IE does not support CSS transforms on SVG content.

Answer (score 0):

If you checkout browser compatibility from 
[Can I Use](http://caniuse.com) 
for **SVG** you will found something like this screenshot

That's mean IE10 does not support `<svg></svg>`.

[image: Browser Compatibility]

Comment: Click on Show all on that very page and you will see IE 10 **does** support SVG.

Comment: IE 10 is having support for svg. If IE 10 not having support for <svg></svg> then how svg path is displaying in IE browser.